# Is there a way to make dialog boxes in Linux?

Tags: linux, msgbox

In Windows, you could simply make a .vbs script (Virtual Basic Script) by doing `x=msgbox()`. But is there a scripting language for Linux?

Comment: There are several utilities for that, actually. `kdialog`, `xmessage`, `gxmessage`, `xdialog`, `gtkdialog`, ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't google for things any better than you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a text/curses program called `dialog`, which you can call from bash, which is a fine scripting language.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/dialog.1.html

And you can try some examples,

```
    $ pushd /usr/share/doc/dialog/examples
    $ ./calendar
```